# Javascript property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, properties, syntax-error

New to Javascript, but I do have experience with Java and Python. I have looked at several other sites to see what's wrong with my code and I know that the error means that the property hasn't been initiated or does not contain anything, but I know I put something in there, so I think I might be getting Java and Javascript mixed up.

Here is my code:

```
    var M=5;
    var N=5;   //where M and N can be changed if needed
    var cellsNotChecked = [];
    var startAt = [Math.floor(Math.random()*M), Math.floor(Math.random()*N)];

    var path = [startAt];
    //then make note of cells visited or not

    for(i=0; i<M+2; i++){
        cellsNotChecked[i]=[];
        for(j=0; j<N+1; j++){
            cellsNotChecked[j].push(i>0&&i<M+1&&j>0&&(i!=startAt[0]+1||j!=startAt[1]+1));
        }   
    }

    var cellsChecked= 1;
    // now keep going until the number of cells checked outweighs the number of cells not checked
    while(cellsChecked<cellsNotChecked.length){
        //list of potential cells to go to next
        var potential = [[startAt[0], startAt[1]+1],        //right: y,x+1
        [startAt[0],startAt[1]-1],                          //left: y, x-1
        [startAt[0]-1,startAt[1]],                          //top: (top left hand corner is 0,0, so) y-1, x
        [startAt[0]+1,startAt[1]]];                         //bottom: y+1, x, 
        var neighboringCells = [];

    //do things
    cellsChecked++;
    }
```

The error shows up at `var potential = [[startAt[0], startAt[1]+1],...` with startAt[0] being underlined all the way to after startAt[1]+1.

Like I said, I think I am giving it values, but I don't know how to check (am using Notepad++).

**Edit notes**

Added curly braces around first for-loop (thank you for catching that,  Mupparthy Ravindranath), but error now occurs at `cellsNotChecked[j].push(...)`.

Full error states: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Part of the problem that I am having is that it appeared to work yesterday before I added a completely un-related function. Now it doesn't work at all. Is it possible for Javascript code to get too long?

Comment: The quoted code does not cause the error in the title of the question: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkd7abq/

Comment: At the beginning of first for loop, it seems an open brace missing.  Is this intentional? But indentation suggests otherwise.

Comment: @MupparthyRavindranath Thank you for catching that! Please see edit notes above?

Comment: You can debug your code by using node debug <progname> and then step through line by line to see where the problem might be.

Comment: @MupparthyRavindranath Is that for Notepad++ or any javascript?

Comment: Use windows cmd terminal or unix terminal